# How to make multiple references to same object in Java

Tags: java, constructor, copy, clone

I am implementing a crossword puzzle backend.

Crossword is composed of slots is composed of cells.

Lets say cell at (3,14) has a value of "a"
I want crossword.changeCellValueByCoordinate(3,14,"x") to do "a"->"x"

Lets say some Slot slot has a head cell at coordinate (3,14)
Slots head can be identified by (2,across) == Cell(3,14)
So when I call slot.getCellValueByNumberAndDirection(2,across) next, it already changed from "a" to "x".

And another method (for the same cell) crossword.getSlot(2,across).getHead also changed from "a" to "x".

How do I make it so all three objects of different types (Crossword, Slot, Cell) has an attribute (perhaps of same name, lets call it "content") that is shared/referenced by all Classes?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to handle this. Here's one way:

I don't care too much for the "Slot" class.  This does nothing to help with the intersections between the clues.

When you look at a crossword puzzle, what do you see? I see a board of empty squares.  Some have little numbers in the corners.  I also see dark blocks I know I can't write in. I see a list of "down" clues, and a list of "across" clues.

No matter what I do, I write on that board of empty squares.  So I'd make a grid-like class called Board that would allow me to write on it. The little number in some squares would be how specific words are indexed.  The contents of each cell could be a space, a letter, or a -1 if the square isn't writable.

You might choose to implement a Square (or Cell) class. It would include a flag stating the instance's ability to be written to. It could include a number signifying the cell to which a clue applies.  There are more elegant ways to do this. Implement this, and we can discuss more advanced class hierarchies.

The Board class would contain an NxN structure (probably an array) of Cell instances.

Another class would be called something like "Clues" that corresponds to the down or across list of clues.  Clues includes a list of Clue instances.

Finally I'd have a Clue class where each instance includes an ID (the 15 in "15 down" for example), and the clue text to be displayed.

I think once you initialize the Board, you'll have all you need to make a nice crossword program.

Comment: I already know how to do all that, I was actually asking specifically about making a reference attribtues in each object (Square, Board) that changes when either reference attribute changes.

Comment: I suppose my answer is "don't do that".  Select the entity that owns the value, and require all other entities to talk to this one to change the value.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do that though? Is that something an interface would do? Or do I have to use global/static variables?

Comment: I can help you through it.  First, create the Cell or Square class. Per what I wrote above, methods should include "isWritable()" and "write(char letter)" at the very least.  Note `write()` should fail if a value has been assigned that is different than letter - that would be a bogus intersection.  Once you have this class, you'll them need a 2-D array of them.  The array should live inside the Board class.  A method in Board could be `write(int id, char direction, String text)`. An example could would be `aBoard.write(12, "down", "FROG");`

Comment: And let Board figure out where "12 down" is located.  So Board manages the placement of the text, and Square manages the actual value of one letter.